# Show current category

Tags: categories

I have this markup:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="imagegallery"}
<div class="element {exp:channel:categories category_group="1" channel="imagegallery" style="linear"}{category_url_title}{/exp:channel:categories}">
    <p>Bla Bla</p>
</div> 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'd like to add the current category as a class. With this markup all categories are added. But I only want the one from this channel entry. How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `{exp:channel:categories}` tag is specifically for displaying a list of *all* categories. You can use the `{categories}` variable pair inside of the `{exp:channel:entries}` loop to get the assigned categories to that entry. You can read more at the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="imagegallery"}
<div class="element {categories backspace="1"}{category_url_title} {/categories}">
    <p>Bla Bla</p>
</div> 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is backspace="1" for?

Comment: The `backspace` parameter removes characters & line breaks at the end of the last iteration in the loop. So I have set it to **1** to remove that space.